# How to find the pixel height of a profile using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, linkedin-api

So here's the issue, Im trying to scroll down linkedin's sales navigator search result page to get the users names. The thing is that the users name isn't loaded until it's in view. So my logic is to scroll down every time one result is captured. The length that should be scrolled down should equal the length of the clients profile. **The question here is, how do I find that length?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with the page you are referring to. Is the length of the entire page finite? e.g. if you keep pressing PgDn, do you eventually get to the bottom or does it scroll for a really, really long time?

Comment: Also, please post the code you are using as a [mcve] so we can see where you are currently at and can make suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You might not need to know "how many pixels?".

Choose a piece of text that should be visible.
Issue a Ctrl-F find command for that text,
and then we will have scrolled down far enough.

You can even Ctrl-G repeat it if needed.

Comment: Manually? Maybe... I don't know how you're going to know what "piece of text" should be visible all the way down the page??? Also, where's the code on how to do this? CTRL+F opens a browser specific search box that can't be interacted with using Selenium, etc.

Comment: I think of Selenium as interacting just like a human would. What?!? It can't e.g. right-click --> open link in new tab, then navigate to that tab? Nor file --> save page as? Nor CMD-F find text? Those are big parts of how I interact with a page, and it sounds like Selenium isn't able to emulate those actions. I had in mind to find expected text, such as "Community Guidelines" or "Education" on a profile page, but it sounds like it's not feasible with the current browser driver. Sigh!